# Finding header font with Chrome's dev tools?

Tags: web-fonts, chrome

I've googled this but this info seems hard to find. Is there a way to identify header fonts using dev tools? I can get the body text, but clicking the various tabs (including COMPUTED) does not produce the header font.

Comment: You simply select the HTML element you want to inspect. The duplicate should explain and give you a few alternatives

Comment: Ah! Didn't see your comment when I was writing my answer. Answers on duplicate should provide additional insight, especially if for some reason dev tools doesn't work for you.

Comment: This doesn't really add anything to the given answers, but I've enjoyed using  [Fontface Ninja](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fontface-ninja/eljapbgkmlngdpckoiiibecpemleclhh).

Comment: Cai, that does not work for me. As explained, I'm trying to get the headers. Your way only shows me the body text.

Comment: Not a dupe because that other thread did not answer my question - how can I find the headers with Chrome's dev tools?

Comment: @TCDesigner devtools shows you the font stack of whatever you have selected, it doesn't care what is a body or header just what DOM elements are selected.

Comment: I'm closing this question. If you still need help TCDesigner than it sounds like you should ask how to find the Header in general since that may be the issue based on what @Cai and the other answer says. If you can locate the Header it should show the font.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Dev Tools should show font of selected element in computed tab. It lists all of the css attributes regarding that element - font-family included.

[image: computed font]

Answer (score 0):

A really great chrome extension I've been using is the CSS Peeper:
https://csspeeper.com/

It's real easy to get fonts, colors and assets and you get all relevant info fast when just clicking on an element.

[image: css peeper]